# Computing geodesics on pseudo-riemannian manifolds

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, computational-geometry, computational-algebra

Consider a pseudo-riemannian manifold $M$ with a metric tensor $g$. Now, given two points $p_1, p_2$ in $M$, how do I *compute* (as in, programatically compute) the geodesic between these two points?

The closest reference I could find [was this, "computing geodescic paths on manifolds"](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Franck.Hetroy/Teaching/ProjetsImage/2006/Bib/sethian_kimmel-1995.pdf), but it appears to require one to triangulate the manifold.

Is there no way to derive closed form / approximate solutions without such methods?

Comment: I am not sure what "compute" means. To begin with, geodesics between two points might not exist; even if they exist, there might be infinitely many of these. Furthermore, do you mean "compute approximately" or "compute symbolically"? An approximate computation is doable by discretizing the geodesic equation. As for a symbolic computation, I do not know. Even the local problem is unclear to me.

Comment: So, my understanding was that even if infinitely many geodesics exist, they all have the same _length_? Which is why one can construct a metric space from a Reimannian manifold?

Comment: Also, any form of approximate answer is fine by me!

Comment: No, geodesics may have different length. Just think about periodic geodesics on the unit circle, which is the simplest example. You have periodic geodesics of any length of the form $2\pi n$. In the Riemannian setting one can ask for a distance-minimizing geodesic (which makes no sense in the indefinite case); such geodesic might not be unique but the length is independent of the minimizing geodesic. (Just like a function can have many points of minima but at most one minimal value.)

Comment: I see, my understanding of geodesics is clearly flawed. So, if I may rephrase, is there an algorithm to compute _shortest path length_ on a reimannian or pseudo reimannian manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you *cannot* do it in the pseudo-Riemannian case. Reasons being that one cannot use a pseudo-Riemannian metric to produce a metric space with the same underlying set, and we have three different notions of geodesic completeness (spacelike, timelike and lightlike) which are not related. There is no Hopf-Rinow theorem in the pseudo-Riemannian case. The closest I know of is the Avez-Seifert theorem for globally hyperbolic spacetimes: given two events, one in the future of the other, there is a maximizing timelike geodesic joining those two events, whose proper time realizes the Lorentzian separation between them.

As for *how* to find a geodesic (once one knows there is one) I can't really say anything, but the point of this answer is emphasizing that there may be no way at all, depending on the case.

Comment: Can you give me references to read about this, please?

Comment: The book that comes to mind is *Global Lorentzian Geometry*, by Beem, Ehrlich and Easley.